# Correct for loop implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, order-of-execution

I've written some code to convert swagger 1 documentation to swagger 2.
I point the conversion method to several resources in an array.
what I find is that it is not executing correctly and see it jump in the debugger all the way to the end of my array (which is of size 34). How do I ensure it loops through my code correctly?

```
for(var i = 0; i < resourcesArray.length; i++) {
    Converter.convert({
        from: 'swagger_1',
        to: 'swagger_2',
        source: 'http://example/' + resourcesArray[i]
    }, function (err, converted) {
        console.log(resourcesArray[i]);
        // [Optional] Fill missing fields with dummy values
        converted.fillMissing();

        // [Optional] Validate converted spec
        var fileName = resourcesArray[i] + '.json';
        fs.writeFileSync(fileName, converted.stringify());
    })
}
```

Comment: that's... what for loops do... it iterates over the whole array executing what's inside. the callback(s) happens some time later, and isn't guaranteed to be in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen victim to JavaScript scoping rules. Try this:

```
resourcesArray.forEach(function (resource) {
    Converter.convert({
        from: 'swagger_1',
        to: 'swagger_2',
        source: 'http://example/' + resource
    }, function (err, converted) {
        console.log(resource);
        // [Optional] Fill missing fields with dummy values
        converted.fillMissing();

        // [Optional] Validate converted spec
        var fileName = resource + '.json';
        fs.writeFileSync(fileName, converted.stringify());
    });
});
```

The problem was that by the time the asynchronous callback `function (err, converted) { ... }` occurs, `i` is equal to `resourcesArray.length` because the iteration is already complete. That is how JavaScript `var` declared variables work. Using a `forEach` loop ensures that the scope always contains the `resource` you're expecting for that operation.

Alternatively, if ES6 is okay, then you could change `var` to `let` and that would also solve the problem because `let`-declared variables use lexical scoping, which means that the for loop block will always contain the expected value of `i` even if it's used inside an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping correctly, however the problem is that JavaScript does not create a closure for `for` body. Since you are kicking off an asynchronous operation within the loop, the value of `i` has changed by the time the asynchronous operation has completed and your callback has been called.

So you're going to have to create a closure immediately within the for loop, store the value you want within the closure, and then call the asynchronous operation while defining the callback within the closure as well.

```
for(var i = 0; i < resourcesArray.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // Do work here with the value i
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, if ES6 is acceptable, `for (let i = 0; i < resourcesArray.length; i++) { /* Do work here with the value i */ }` would also work.

Answer (score -2):

This might be happening because there is an asynchronous call inside your `for` loop. You need to freeze the value of `i`, for each iteration. You can use `closure()` for this. In case you want to keep track of when all iterations have completed, you can keep a counter:
    var counter = resourcesArray.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < resourcesArray.length; i++) {
      var resources = resourcesArray[i];

```
  (function( resources, i ){
     Converter.convert({
        from: 'swagger_1',
        to: 'swagger_2',
        source: 'http://example/' + resources
    }, function (err, converted) {
        console.log(resources);
        // [Optional] Fill missing fields with dummy values
        converted.fillMissing();

        // [Optional] Validate converted spec
        var fileName = resources + '.json';
        fs.writeFileSync(fileName, converted.stringify());

        counter--;
        if( counter <= 0 )
        {
          //next();
        }
    })
  })(resources, i );    
}//for
```